# How to move file from one in another S3 Bucket after time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, amazon-glacier

How to move file from one in another S3 Bucket after time?

i checked this thread: [Is it possible to automatically move objects from an S3 bucket to another one after some time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098677/is-it-possible-to-automatically-move-objects-from-an-s3-bucket-to-another-one-af)

but i don't want to use the Glacier option, because our files a really small. Is there another option?

**EDIT:**

Requirement is to mark files as invalid (there is a metadata table where we change an attribute for this) and later on to delete them. (invalid means = e.g. older as some date...maybe 30 days). After that, this invalid files should be deleted after, we say 120 days.

Why to move files?

1. Separate by business requirement (invalid vs. valid files) - don't have to check this attribute again (whether it's invalid or valid)
2. less files to iterate over, if we may want to iterate over valid files
3. important: 'S3 PUT event' of new bucket can invoke a
   lambda function: this lambda function can do other stuff. Like
   change attribute (valid/invalid/deleted) in our dynamoDB table.

**Yes, we can also renounce the use of moving files. But i don't see a way how to execute lambda functions after a delay of 30 days.**

Best regards

Comment: If you want to move files from one in another s3 bucket automatically after some time. Please write a amazon Lambda script to do so. Lambda script will execute once your file dropped into Bucket-1 and you can make the delay and start doing migration process to Bucket-2. Hope this high level solution makes you go further.

Comment: how i write a lambda script, which moves my files after some time? Then this lamda function has to run all time long?

Comment: okay, its possible to create a watchdog alarm/event dynamically within my lambda function. Do you mean that?

Comment: Yes, you can do control in that way via lambda script.

Comment: Can you please tell us more about **why** you wish to **move** the file after some time? There might be another way to achieve what you are seeking.

Comment: Hey John, i edited the answer and explained the requirement. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to [schedule lambda function execution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html) using CloudWatch [scheduled events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html)

The design should include:

- Implementation of Lambda function which identifies and moves required objects in S3
- Scheduled expression rule with desired schedule. Cloudwatch supports `crontab` expression like `aws events put-rule --schedule-expression
  "cron(0 0 1 * ? *)" --name ObjectExpirationRule`
- Assign the rule to the lambda `aws events put-targets --rule ObjectExpirationRule --targets '[{"1", "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:MyLambdaFunction"}]'`